# Are the mean and variance of a set equals the sum of its means and variaces

Tags: statistics, variance, means

I'm not so fit in statistics and I found some controverse answers on the internet so I'm asking here.

I have a set $A$ with 10439 samples. The set is not of unique values and many of the sample values occur more than once. Now I want to calculate the mean and the variance of the set, but there is a limitation. I can't calculate for the whole set at once so I had to split it into $N$ batches. Now lets say I have $N=73$ batches $A_{1}, ... ,A_{73}$ created form the big set $A$. Do those hold?

1. $mean(A) = \frac{mean(A_{1}) + ... + mean(A_{73})}{N}$
2. $var(A) = \frac{var(A_{1}) + ... + var(A_{73})}{N}$

If not then how can I achieve my goal using the batches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statement 1 and Statement 2 are both untrue.

Statement 1 is not true because the means in the average are not weighted by the size of the set. For example if $A_1 = \{1\}$ and $A_2 = \{2,2,2,2\}$ then $\operatorname{mean}(A_1 \cup A_2) = 1.8$ but $\tfrac{\operatorname{mean}(A_1) + \operatorname{mean}(A_2)}{2} = \frac{1+2}{2} = 1.5$. The correct formula is
$$
\operatorname{mean}(A) = \frac{|A_1|\operatorname{mean}(A_1) + |A_2|\operatorname{mean}(A_2) + \cdots + |A_N|\operatorname{mean}(A_N)}{|A_1|+|A_2|+\cdots+|A_N|}
$$
where $|A_i|$ gives the number of elements in the set $A$. To see this, expand
$$
\operatorname{mean}(A) = \frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{a\in A}a = \frac{1}{|A|}\biggl(\frac{|A_1|}{|A_1|}\sum_{a\in A_1}a + \frac{|A_2|}{|A_2|}\sum_{a\in A_2}a + \cdots + \frac{|A_2|}{|A_2|}\sum_{a\in A_N}a\biggr)
$$
and observe that $\tfrac{1}{|A_i|}\sum_{a \in A_i} a$ is exactly $\operatorname{mean}(A_i)$.

Statement 2 is untrue for effectively the same reason. One way to compute the correct $\operatorname{var}(A)$ in batches is to compute $s_i = \sum_{a\in A_i}a^2$ for every batch $i=1,2,\ldots,N$. At this point $$\operatorname{var}(A) = \frac{s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_N}{|A_1| + |A_2| + \cdots + |A_N|} - \operatorname{mean}(A)^2,$$ where $\operatorname{mean}(A)$ was computed as above.

Comment: Thank you very much I've calculated the first Statement correctly. I've had to calculate the variance of each batch separately and sequentially for each of the 73 batches with $$var(A_i) = \frac{1}{|A_i|}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{|A_i|} (a_i - \mu_{A_i})^2$$ Is there a way to add my sequential results to get the whole variance of (A)?

Comment: It turns out that $\sigma_{A_i}^2 = \tfrac{s_i}{|A_i|} - \mu_{A_i}^2$ as well, so with $\sigma_{A_i}^2$ already computed you can find $s_i = |A_i|(\sigma_{A_i}^2 + \mu_{A_i}^2)$ and use the formula above.

Comment: Thanks again! The calculation of the second Statement worked with $$var(A)=\frac{|A_1|(\sigma^2_{A_1} + \mu^2_{A_1}) + |A_2|(\sigma^2_{A_2} + \mu^2_{A_2}) + \cdots + |A_N|(\sigma^2_{A_N} + \mu^2_{A_N})}{|A_1| + |A_2| + \cdots + |A_N|}-mean(A)^2$$